# Cannot access a state object by key in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I want to be able to access a state object I set the interfaces for that manner but I am still getting the error for some reason could you please explain what is happening ? and how to solve it , i am getting

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'stateInterface'.
the Erorr is showing on selected[target]

```js
interface List {
    name: string;
    id: string;
  }
  interface stateInterface {
    name: string | keyof List;
    id: string | keyof List;
  }
  const initialState: stateInterface = {
    name: '',
    id: '',
  };
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(initialState);
  
  const returnValueOnCondition = (e: React.FocusEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const target = e.currentTarget.name; //  target will return name or id
    if (foucusedRef.current && selected[target] === '') foucusedRef.current = false;
  };
  
   <TextField
        autoComplete='off'
        name='name'
        value={selected.name}
        onBlur={returnValueOnCondition}
   />
   
      <TextField
        autoComplete='off'
        name='id'
        value={selected.name}
        onBlur={returnValueOnCondition}
   />
```

Comment: @raina77ow sadly no

Comment: Ah, my mistake, didn't catch the error properly. What should happen if `target` is neither `'name'` nor `'id'`, but some other string? HTMLInputElement on its own doesn't provide limitations like these.

Comment: @raina77ow it cannot be since the the reference is set in advance I am not targeting the value of that but rather the name it self so I can access the object by either name or id to see what is there and apply the condition

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something obvious here, but: I'm looking at this function and all I can see is `currentTarget` being typed as `HTMLInputElement`. That means its `name` property can be equal to any string. How exactly the function is used (and which value is provided as its argument) is not really relevant to compiler.

Comment: If you're 1000% sure `name` of that input element is either `name` or `id` (as said in that comment - which shouldn't actually be there), use type assertion to ensure it's `keyof stateInterface`. Beware, though, that it might bite you at some point.

Comment: I see, but that's exactly what I said before: your `returnValueOnCondition` is measured not on how it's actually used (how TS should guess that? by running the code?), but how it *can* be used. And it can be used on any other TextField element with `name` no longer equal to either of those.